# jQuery sortable() doesn't run in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

The following piece of code works as it should when I use it as an html file, but as soon as I want to use it as a partial for a view in my rails application it doesn't work anymore :(

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable-list').sortable({
      axis: "y"
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="sortable-list">
    <li id="order_option_1">testWordA</li>
    <li id="order_option_2">testWordB</li>
    <li id="order_option_3">testWordC</li>
    <li id="order_option_4">testWordD</li>
  </ul>
  <br />
</body>
```

I tried to use easier jQuery methods like `hide()`, which runs perfectly in my application. I use Rails 3.2.16 and Ruby 1.9.3. Is it possible that some setting in my application blocks the `sortable()` method?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is the partial view being loaded dynamically?

Comment: The console says, that the partial is rendered, gives me a `200` status code and doesn't show any errors. The partial is loaded inside a form. I don't know if this is considered dynamically (could you tell me, when something is considered statically and when dynamically loaded?). Could this (being part of a form) have something to do with the failure of the sortable() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from jQuery to [Rubaxa](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/) and the following code is working in the partial as well:

```
<ul id="sortable-list">
  <li id="order_option_1">testWordA</li>
  <li id="order_option_2">testWordB</li>
  <li id="order_option_3">testWordC</li>
  <li id="order_option_4">testWordD</li>
</ul>
<br />
<script src="/scripts/Sortable.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var sortable_list = document.getElementById('sortable-list');
  var sortable = Sortable.create(sortable_list); 
</script>
```